# jQuery validate, submitting with submitHandler

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have an HTML-form

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="myform" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="supmit" name="submit" id="submit"  value="submit" />
</form>
```

And a code of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var validator = $("#myform").validate({
        ignore: ".ignore",
        rules: {...},
        messages: {...},
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('usr.php?resetpw', $(this).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
                form.submit();
                alert(data.inf);
            },'json');
        },
});
```

and also PHP-code usr.php that doesn't get $_POST-variables (`isset($_POST['email'])` = `false`)

```
if(isset($_GET['resetpw'])) {
    $loggingData = array(
        'inf' => utf8_encode("Your email address is: ".$_POST['email']),
        'errorEmail' => '',
        'mailExists' => '',
        'success' => '',
    );
}
echo json_encode($loggingData);
```

What is a correct code that post variables reached to PHP?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of logging have you done? Have you checked the request in Firebug/Developer tools to see if the data is actually getting sent? Try `$('#myform').serialize()`, `this` may not be referring to the form inside that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked the source of `validate` plugin from here http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js

and it's calling `submitHandler` like this

```
 validator.settings.submitHandler.call( validator, validator.currentForm );
```

Which means `this` will refer to the `validator object` not the `form`, so use the `form` argument to refer to the form and serialize it's fields like this

```
 $(form).serialize()
```

Answer (score 2):

Serialize `form` not `this` .
so submithandler will looks like below..

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('usr.php?resetpw', $(form).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
            form.submit();
            alert(data.inf);
        },'json');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form_id").trigger('submit');
```

try this