# jQuery Validate submitHandler Not Working With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have the following form:

```
    <form id="squatsForm"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="squatsVal" value="Squats" />
        <input type="hidden" name="exercise" value="squats" />
        <input type="submit" id="submitSquats" value="Add Squats"/><br />
    </form>
```

I want to validate the form and then send the data in that form via Ajax for further processing. I'm trying to use `submitHandler` so the form does not perform the default action of loading a new page with a POST request and instead fires my Ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#squatsForm').validate({
        rules: {
            amount: {
                required: true,
                number: true    
               }   
            },  
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post(
                "submitWorkout1",
                form.serialize(),
                function(data) {
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#squats").html(jsonData['amount']);
                }); 
            }   
        });
```

However, when I try to input data with my form, it reloads the page and does not perform the Ajax request.

Before I implemented the validation, my Ajax request was working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it validate your form?

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment to your question, otherwise I'd have simply asked you if you just forgot to end the ready function or just missed it while copying-pasting.

I used your code and confirmed that it did not run. When I clicked on **Add Squats** button, it just reloaded the page irrespective of whether or not I had a proper value in the **amount** field.

However, when I added a `});` to the end of your code to properly end the `$(document).ready(function () {`, it worked!

It performs the validation and also fires an alert I put as the first statement in the `submitHandler`.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#squatsForm').validate({
            rules: {
                amount: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.post(
                            "submitWorkout1",
                           form.serialize(),
                           function (data) {
                               var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                               $("#squats").html(jsonData['amount']);
                           }
                      );
            }
        });
    });
```

I hope the solution to your problem is as simple as ending the `ready` function properly. If it isn't let's debug this further together! Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the 'form' variable in submitHandler function with jquery function will fix it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#squatsForm').validate({
        rules: {
            amount: {
                required: true,
                number: true    
               }   
            },  
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post(
                "submitWorkout1",
                $(form).serialize(),
                function(data) {
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#squats").html(jsonData['amount']);
                }); 
            }   
        });
```

Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861735/1497042